# How can I retrieve the address of an external library in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

I'm currently working on a Solidity project that involves using external libraries. I need to access the address of an external library within my contract.

Is there a way to retrieve an external library's address in Solidity?

I've gone through the Solidity documentation but couldn't find a direct way to obtain the address of an external library.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And yet ! Docs most of the time **do** have the answer.

Here it is:

[image: external libraries addresses]

This : https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.21/contracts.html#libraries

and this : https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.21/contracts.html#function-signatures-and-selectors-in-libraries

should give you all you need to find your answer.
However I think that instead of finding the address of an external library maybe you could just use its code and deploy it with your contracts ?

Comment: Thanks! It works!